# Objective C Printing: How to set header content?

Tags: cocoa, image, printing, header, nsview

I want to print a specific NSView. When I do this, I wish to add content to the header of the print page.

e.g. If the NSView contains a picture of a cat, when I press print, print preview shows up with the picture of the cat. I want the print out to be a picture of a cat, with the caption: "Cat" in the header, which I do not want visible on the original NSView.

Also, if this is possible, is it also possible to add images too?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't confuse the language (Objective-C) with the API (Cocoa). The latter is what handles views and printing, the former is the language in which it was written. :-) Retagged for clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overwrite the method `- (NSAttributedString *)pageHeader` in your `NSView` subclass. See Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/ReferenceNSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/pageHeader).

Note that headers are generated only if the user defaults contain the key `NSPrintHeaderAndFooter` with the value YES.

As for images, those can be added to a `NSAttributedString` using a `NSTextAttachment`.

Comment: I overwrote the method pageHeader, with a custom subclass called PrintView. This works, but there's a really annoying warning:

"Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct PrintView *', expected 'struct NSView *' when passing argument 1 of 'printOperationWithView:printInfo:' from distinct Objective-C type

The printout is fine, and the program works, but is there a way to get rid of the message?

Comment: Sounds like the compiler doesn't know that your PrintView is a subclass of NSView. Did you import PrintView.h where you called the print method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw things differently on the screen than the printer, you can use the isDrawingToScreen method in your drawRect: method.

Eg:

```
if (![[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] isDrawingToScreen]) {
//draw printer headers and images
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just required the header at the moment, but I might need to use this in the future!

Comment: How do you display the not visible part of the view using drawRect ?